# Can I safely edit Nginx Systemd unit file (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service) supplied by nginx package?

Tags: debian, nginx, systemd

I've installed Nginx with `apt install nginx` on a Debian 9.2 host. It works fine, but looking in the Systemd journal with `journalctl -u nginx`, I get the hilarious:

> Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

Turns out Systemd reuses the "Description" field in the "[Unit]" section of the unit file, and sure enough for `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` it says:

> Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server

Is this a joke by Debian Nginx maintainers or someone else? Even Systemd documentation at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Description= says:

> Bad examples are "high-performance light-weight HTTP server" (too generic)

So I am thinking to edit the "Description" field to give it a more ehm, descriptive value, but I am not sure how this will work when I will be updating nginx package as part of system update or upgrade -- will I be warned of a conflict if another version of `nginx.service` is attempted installed? I know this is the case with package configuration files, does this also apply to other kinds of files from the package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rough rule, anything in `/usr` or `/lib` should be considered read-only, and especially anything that was installed by a package. (There are rare unfortunate exceptions.) Unless a file was specially marked in the package, upgrades will simply overwrite it.

The recommended way of changing various systemd files is to copy them to `/etc`. For example, the unit file `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service` will override the one in /usr/lib. (It will even override the autogenerated init.d service units.) Use the tool `systemd-delta` to see diffs of all overridden units.

Well, I say "recommended" because it also works with things like udev rules and such... But an even better method is to override just parts of a unit using "drop-in" files `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/foobar.conf` – this only needs two lines, the section name `[Unit]` and your new `Description=` setting; the rest will be inherited from /usr/lib.

In both cases you can use `systemctl edit [--full]` to just open an editor and make your changes.

Finally the generic Debian option is to tell the packaging system (dpkg) to avoid updating a specific file, no matter where it is located. You can "divert" the real file elsewhere using `dpkg-divert`. Other distros have similar features, e.g. Arch's pacman uses `NoExtract=` and `NoUpgrade=`.